# How to create a class that can not be inherited by other classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can anyone tell how to create class so that it can not be inherited by any other classes.

```
class A {
  public :
          int a;
          int b;
};

class B : class A {
   public :
           int c;
};
```

in above program i do not want to allow other classes to be inherited by class B

Comment: It's not clear to me. You want to allow only `B` inherite from `A`?

Comment: Do you really mean "inherited *by*" or "inherited *from*" `class B`?

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this?  What problems would it cause?

Answer (score 13):

Mark the class `final` (since C++11):

```
class A final {
public :
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use the `final` keyword, just as the other answer mentioned. **And that should be the recommended solution.**

However, if have to struggle with C++03 / C++98, you can make the class's constructors `private`, and create object of this class with a factory method or class.

```
class A {
private:
    A(int i, int j) : a(i), b(j) {}
    // other constructors.

    friend A* create_A(int i, int j);
    // maybe other factory methods.
};

A* create_A(int i, int j) {
    return new A(i, j);
}
// maybe other factory methods.
```